# How Google+ animates their logo on the left of the navigation as the scrollbar shrinks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How does [Google+](https://plus.google.com/) animate their logo to slide in on the navigation bar when it shrinks?  I can get the scrollbar to shrink on scroll, but not like they do it, and I can't figure out how they animate the icons.  I really just want to have that functionality on a navigation bar.

Comment: Post the code that you've tried. What exactly are you looking for in terms of an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all CSS there mixed up with some JavaScript. They detect the current scroll location of the user and depending on that value, they change the values of the Images and Logos and the elements.

This way, they provide the UI for the users. You don't need to animate the icons, just show them in the tray that you're hiding untill the user is at the top.

Comment: But the red logo that slides into view as the navigation becomes fixed has to be a bit of JavaScript they hooked in on scroll height, and animates the logo into view?

Comment: Yes exactly. They just set it to be visible in the bar, when the user scrolls down a bit.